# How to create a .bat loop that creates a new cmd window and runs a different loop/function?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following code:

```
set cont=3
:window 
start segredo.bat 
if %cont% equ 0 goto windowend
set /a cont=cont-1 
goto window
:windowend

:loopstart
echo spam
goto loopstart
:loopend
```

My objective was to open 3 cmd windows and run the echo spam loop in each one of them. Instead, it start opening infinite cmd windows without running loopstart. I'm kind of new to bat language so is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /l %%a in (1 1 3) do start "" cmd /q /c"for /l %%b in (0) do echo spam"
```

Inside out

- An infinite loop is needed to do the `echo`, so a simply numeric `for /l` loop is used. Just a *"iterate from 0 to 1 in steps of 0"*, a `for /l %%b in (0 0 1)` but abreviated.
- As three separate instances are required, the command is placed inside a `cmd` instance
- We use an aditional numeric `for /l` loop, to `start` each of the `cmd` instances. To prevent problems with the commands, as the `start` command handles the first quoted argument as the window title, a pair of empty quotes are included.

Comment: could you please explain how you got there?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `start segredo.bat` with `call segredo.bat`.